# Extract content of specific div class php dom

Tags: php, html, dom, extract

Hi there i want to extract a specific div class only from a specific website.

Here is what i have but it doesn't work for some reason, I get loads of errors::

```
$page = file_get_contents('https://extcall.17track.net/en/track#apitype=1&nums=RK444760227FR');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div) {
    // Loop through the DIVs looking for one withan id of "content"
    // Then echo out its contents (pardon the pun)
    if ($div->getAttribute('class') === 'tracklist-fill') {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

what i want to extract is the tracking results only without the brand or title or other elements

what am i doing wrong ?

cheers

these are the errors im getting

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag main invalid in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : p in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : p in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7 
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 in /volume1/web/track/test3.php on line 7
```

and this is the html snippet from the website you see above in file get contents

body > main > div > section.yq-panel.yq-panel-tracklist.jcTrackContainer > div > div.tracklist-fill

```
<div class="tracklist-fill">
    <div class="tracklist-ps-transit">
        <div class="yqcr-ps" data-ps="10"><a class="btn btn-icon fa-PS_10 ps-bgcolor-10 waves-effect" title="In transit"
                                             href="//help.17track.net/hc/en-us/articles/228084227#10"
                                             yqg-events="{C:功能操作,A:结果页-查看帮助,L:包裹状态_10}" target="_blank"
                                             data-icon=""></a>
            <div data-name=""><p class="text-uppercase" title="RK444760227FR">RK444760227FR</p>
                <p class="text-capitalize" title="In transit">In transit</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="yqcr-transit">
            <div class="from" data-key="06051">
                <div class="base-info" data-carrier-type="fc">
                    <div><span title="France" data-country="">France</span> <i title="La Poste">La Poste</i></div>
                </div>
                <div class="action-info"><a class="btn btn-icon btn-pure btn-default fa-home waves-effect waves-circle"
                                            target="_blank" href="http://www.laposte.fr/"
                                            yqg-events="{C:功能操作,A:结果页-跳转运输商官网,L:06051}"
                                            title="Go to the carrier's official website."> </a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="to" data-key="07071">
                <div class="base-info" data-carrier-type="sc">
                    <div><span title="Greece" data-country="">Greece</span> <i title="ELTA">ELTA</i></div>
                </div>
                <div class="action-info"><a class="btn btn-icon btn-pure btn-default fa-home waves-effect waves-circle"
                                            target="_blank" href="http://www.elta.gr/"
                                            yqg-events="{C:功能操作,A:结果页-跳转运输商官网,L:07071}"
                                            title="Go to the carrier's official website."> </a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tracklist-events scrollable is-enabled scrollable-vertical" yq-data="scrollBox"
         style="position: relative;">
        <div class="scrollable-container" style="height: 360px; width: 909px;">
            <div class="scrollable-content" style="width: 892px;">
                <div class="hide"><p data-newevents="">FRANCE, DEPARTURE FROM OUTWARD OFFICE OF EXCHANGE</p>
                    <time data-newtime="">2018-12-11 07:15</time>
                </div>
                <div class="yqcr-details">
                    <dl class="des-block" data-from="en">
                        <dt><span>Destination</span> <span>: Greece</span> <span>- Tracking consuming: 958 ms</span>
                        </dt>
                        <dd class="new"><i></i>
                            <div>
                                <time>2018-12-11 07:15</time>
                                <p>FRANCE, DEPARTURE FROM OUTWARD OFFICE OF EXCHANGE</p></div>
                        </dd>
                        <dd class=""><i></i>
                            <div>
                                <time>2018-12-08 09:07</time>
                                <p>FRANCE, POSTING/COLLECTION</p></div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl class="ori-block" data-from="fr">
                        <dt><span>Origin</span> <span>: France</span> <span>- Tracking consuming: 1452 ms</span></dt>
                        <dd class=""><i></i>
                            <div>
                                <time>2018-12-08 00:00</time>
                                <p>CHAMPAGNOLE, Pris en charge</p></div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-bar scrollable-bar-vertical is-disabled scrollable-bar-hide" draggable="false">
            <div class="scrollable-bar-handle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and these are the elements i want in the picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wLOR.jpg

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting?

Comment: Can you also post a HTML snippet showing what the page structure looks like?

Comment: added above thanks

Comment: anyone please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting all those errors because the HTML that you are trying to parse is invalid i.e. it is missing required tags, etc.

**UPDATE:**

After examining the content of that page you are trying to parse, I can see that the info you are interested in is rendered using Javascript in the browser. The actual HTML returned just has some templates in it with no tracking data.

```
<script type="text/template" id="tracking-loading-tpl">
    <%for(var i = 0,len = arrTrackNums.length; i < len; i++){%>
        <div class="tracklist-item tracklist-tracking"
            data-tracknumber="<%=arrTrackNums[i]%>"
            data-trackitem="<%=arrTrackNums[i]%>">
            <div class="tracklist-fill">
                <div class="tracklist-ps-transit"> <%==packageStatus[i]%></div>
                <div class="yqcr-loading-list"> <%==loading%></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tracklist-da">
                <div class="gad-container" id="DA_V6-Extcall-Track"></div>
            </div>
            <%==action%>
        </div>
    <%}%>
</script>
```

So you won't be able to get the data by loading the page with `file_get_contents()` and `DOMDocument`.

**ORIGINAL:**

You could using HTML Tidy to clean up the HTML:

```
$page = file_get_contents('https://extcall.17track.net/en/track#apitype=1&nums=RK444760227FR');

$config = array(
    'output-html' => 'yes',
    'clean' => 'yes',
);
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($tidy);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div) {
    // Loop through the DIVs looking for one withan id of "content"
    // Then echo out its contents (pardon the pun)
    if ($div->getAttribute('class') === 'tracklist-fill') {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: tidy isn't installed on my server cant i do it otherwise ? cheers

Comment: used wampserver with tidy installed same errors continue :/

Comment: Well, you may need to use a different method since the DOMDocument class needs well formed HTML. Can you post the "cleaned" HTML from Tidy?

Comment: I'm able to load the page snippet you provided by loading as XML instead of HTML. You could try that.

Comment: Actually, upon further investigation the HTML returned does not contain the data you are interested in. See updated answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer so there is nothing to could be done then.. :/